# Command line compiler for XTend

Tags: eclipse, command-line, compiler-construction, xtend

Hi all
I've found XTend (http://xtend-lang.org) and it really sounds great! But, I can't see any standalone command line compiler for this language. It seems only to run under eclipse. I've done some research, and found some people saying, that it has a command line compiler, but I can't find a download link.
Does the compiler exist, standalone, or do you need eclipse to use it?
Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not documented, but there is indeed a command line compiler in the Xtend code base - the same one used by the [Maven plug-in](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/download.html#MavenSupport) (that is documented in the Xtend homepage).

If Maven plug-in does not work for you, then you could download the standalone jar version directly from the Maven repository at http://build.eclipse.org/common/xtend/maven/org/eclipse/xtend/org.eclipse.xtend.standalone/2.3.1/ (for version 2.3.1), and execute the [org.eclipse.xtend.core.compiler.batch.Main](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext/blob/master/plugins/org.eclipse.xtend.core/src/org/eclipse/xtend/core/compiler/batch/Main.java) class from it.

This class  executes the xtend compiler, and usage information can be displayed (also readable from the [source file](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext/blob/master/plugins/org.eclipse.xtend.core/src/org/eclipse/xtend/core/compiler/batch/Main.java)).

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was searching for

Answer (score 2):

You can use the xtend standalone compiler. For my case I copied the following .jar files to a folder named xtendc:

```
com.google.guava_21.0.0.v20170206-1425.jar
com.google.inject_3.0.0.v201312141243.jar
javax.inject_1.0.0.v20091030.jar
org.antlr.runtime_3.2.0.v201101311130.jar
org.apache.log4j_1.2.15.v201012070815.jar
org.eclipse.emf.common_2.15.0.v20180914-1817.jar
org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi_2.15.0.v20180706-1146.jar
org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.16.0.v20181124-0637.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.10.200.v20181021-1645.jar
org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.16.0.v20181130-1748.jar
org.eclipse.xtend.core_2.16.0.v20181203-1347.jar
org.eclipse.xtend.lib.macro_2.16.0.v20181203-0507.jar
org.eclipse.xtext.common.types_2.16.0.v20181203-0528.jar
org.eclipse.xtext.util_2.16.0.v20181203-0514.jar
org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib_2.16.0.v20181203-0507.jar
org.eclipse.xtext.xbase_2.16.0.v20181203-0528.jar
org.eclipse.xtext_2.16.0.v20181203-0514.jar
org.objectweb.asm_7.0.0.v20181030-2244.jar
```

And then, in that folder I executed the CLI main class of the batch compiler:

```
java -cp "*" org.eclipse.xtend.core.compiler.batch.Main -d <path-to-xtend-gen-folder>  -useCurrentClassLoader <path-to-src-folder>
```

CLI usage of main class is documented to be as following:

```
Usage: Main <options> <source directories>
where possible options include:
-d <directory>                      Specify where to place generated xtend files
-tp <path>                          Temp directory to hold generated stubs and classes
-cp <path>                          Specify where to find user class files
-encoding <encoding>                Specify character encoding used by source files
-javaSourceVersion <version>        Create Java Source compatible to this version. Can be: 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 9, 10
-noSuppressWarningsAnnotation       Don't put @SuppressWarnings() into generated Java Code
-generateGeneratedAnnotation        Put @Generated into generated Java Code
-includeDateInGeneratedAnnnotation  If -generateGeneratedAnnotation is used, add the current date/time.
-generateAnnotationComment <string> If -generateGeneratedAnnotation is used, add a comment.
-useCurrentClassLoader              Use current classloader as parent classloader
-writeTraceFiles                    Write Trace-Files
```

so you will need to pass your classpath there.