# Command line compiler for Xtend doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, compiler-construction, xtext, xtend

I am trying to learn how to compile xtend / xtext code. I followed two advices, [this one](https://github.com/funatsufumiya/xtend-standalone-compiler), which I found a cleaner and more practical solution and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14092217/command-line-compiler-for-xtend).
But neither worked. I feel like I got closer trying the first way (using ant and ivy)

But following README I got the error:
[image: error 1]

I tried to add `<dependency org="org.eclipse.xtend" name="org.eclipse.xtend.core" rev="2.19.0" conf="web->default"/>` in `ivy.xml`
but..

[image: error 2]

So, i just need compile and run a HelloWorld

Comment: is there any reason not to use ant or gradle or maven?
did you try to stip the signatures from manifests?

Comment: btw did you simply to to provide an absolute path (first error) `-d /data/eclipse-workspaces/ws-dev-cdietric-largedevices/demo/src-gen2 -cp /home/cdietric/.p2/pool/plugins/com.google.guava_15.0.0.v201403281430.jar:/home/cdietric/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib_2.13.0.v20171012-0742.jar:/home/cdietric/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.xtend.lib_2.13.0.v20171012-0742.jar:/home/cdietric/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.xtend.lib.macro_2.13.0.v20171012-0742.jar /data/eclipse-workspaces/ws-dev-cdietric-largedevices/demo/src
` (+ a classpath)